# hiding parent when a span contains no content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, is-empty

I've been up and down the site and various questions related to this, I cannot find a resolution for this.

I'm try to hide my parent div "row" whenever my span "specvalue" contains no data

```
    <div class="container-fluid" id="itmSpecsTbl">
 <div class="row" id="row"><div class="col-xs-6" align="left"><b>Accuracy</b> </div><div class="col-xs-6" align="right"><span id="specvalue"><%=getAttribute('item','127559','custitem1','')%></span> </div></div>
 <div class="row" id="row"><div class="col-xs-6" align="left"><b>Drive Type</b> </div><div class="col-xs-6" align="right"><span id="specvalue"><%=getAttribute('item','127559','custitem2','')%></span> </div></div>
 <div class="row" id="row"><div class="col-xs-6" align="left"><b>Free Speed</b> </div><div class="col-xs-6" align="right"><span id="specvalue"><%=getAttribute('item','127559','custitem4','')%></span> RPM</div></div>
 <div class="row" id="row"><div class="col-xs-6" align="left"><b>Increments</b> </div><div class="col-xs-6" align="right"><span id="specvalue"><%=getAttribute('item','127559','custitem5','')%></span> </div></div>
 <div class="row" id="row"><div class="col-xs-6" align="left"><b>Length</b> </div><div class="col-xs-6" align="right"><span id="specvalue"><%=getAttribute('item','127559','custitem6','')%></span> In</div></div>
 <div class="row" id="row"><div class="col-xs-6" align="left"><b>Length</b> </div><div class="col-xs-6" align="right"><span id="specvalue"><%=getAttribute('item','127559','custitem7','')%></span> mm</div></div>
 <div class="row" id="row"><div class="col-xs-6" align="left"><b>Max Air Consumption</b> </div><div class="col-xs-6" align="right"><span id="specvalue"><%=getAttribute('item','127559','custitem8','')%></span> </div></div>
 <div class="row" id="row"><div class="col-xs-6" align="left"><b>Air Inlet (NPT)</b> </div><div class="col-xs-6" align="right"><span id="specvalue"><%=getAttribute('item','127559','custitem37','')%></span> </div></div>  
 <div class="row" id="row"><div class="col-xs-6" align="left"><b>Min Torque</b> </div><div class="col-xs-6" align="right"><span id="specvalue"><%=getAttribute('item','127559','custitem9','')%></span> ft lb</div></div>
 <div class="row" id="row"><div class="col-xs-6" align="left"><b>Max Torque</b> </div><div class="col-xs-6" align="right"><span id="specvalue"><%=getAttribute('item','127559','custitem10','')%></span> ft lb</div></div>
 <div class="row" id="row"><div class="col-xs-6" align="left"><b>Min Torque</b> </div><div class="col-xs-6" align="right"><span id="specvalue"><%=getAttribute('item','127559','custitem11','')%></span> in lb</div></div>
 <div class="row" id="row"><div class="col-xs-6" align="left"><b>Max Torque</b> </div><div class="col-xs-6" align="right"><span id="specvalue"><%=getAttribute('item','127559','custitem12','')%></span> in lb</div></div>
 <div class="row" id="row"><div class="col-xs-6" align="left"><b>Min Torque</b> </div><div class="col-xs-6" align="right"><span id="specvalue"><%=getAttribute('item','127559','custitem13','')%></span> in oz</div></div>
 <div class="row" id="row"><div class="col-xs-6" align="left"><b>Max Torque</b> </div><div class="col-xs-6" align="right"><span id="specvalue"><%=getAttribute('item','127559','custitem14','')%></span> in oz</div></div>
 <div class="row" id="row"><div class="col-xs-6" align="left"><b>Min Torque</b> </div><div class="col-xs-6" align="right"><span id="specvalue"><%=getAttribute('item','127559','custitem15','')%></span> kgf cm</div></div>
 <div class="row" id="row"><div class="col-xs-6" align="left"><b>Max Torque</b> </div><div class="col-xs-6" align="right"><span id="specvalue"><%=getAttribute('item','127559','custitem16','')%></span> kgf cm</div></div>
 <div class="row" id="row"><div class="col-xs-6" align="left"><b>Capacity</b> </div><div class="col-xs-6" align="right"><span id="specvalue"><%=getAttribute('item','127559','custitemfi0073','')%></span> lbs</div></div>
 <div class="row" id="row"><div class="col-xs-6" align="left"><b>Min Reach</b> </div><div class="col-xs-6" align="right"><span id="specvalue"><%=getAttribute('item','127559','custitemfi0103','')%></span> in</div></div>
 <div class="row" id="row"><div class="col-xs-6" align="left"><b>Max Reach</b> </div><div class="col-xs-6" align="right"><span id="specvalue"><%=getAttribute('item','127559','custitemfi0104','')%></span> in</div></div> 
</div>
```

The "getAttribute" is used to pull data of my items, when there's no data. it's blank - no spaces, nothing.

I've tried using :empty, :blank

```
#specvalue:empty #row, #specvalue:blank #row { display: none; }
```

This got me nowhere, same with jquery

```
$("#specvalue:empty").parent().hide();
```

Nothing has worked so far, I've even tried placing the script inside the `<head>` tag, and even below after the tech documents are called.

Do you think I need to be more specific with the CSS? I see it works on other examples, but not on this.

Comment: First things first, IDs need to be unique.. you can't have multiple ids `row` or `specvalue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've removed the duplicate `id="row"` and replaced `id="specvalue"` with `class="specvalue"`. Then with some simple jquery I've hidden all rows with empty specvalue.

Note: always keep in minde id's **always** have to be unique within the full html page!

```js
$('.specvalue').each(function(i, v) {
  if ($(this).html() === '') {
    $(this).closest('.row').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" id="itmSpecsTbl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6" align="left"><b>Accuracy</b> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" align="right"><span class="specvalue">A</span> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6" align="left"><b>Drive Type</b> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" align="right"><span class="specvalue"></span> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6" align="left"><b>Free Speed</b> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" align="right"><span class="specvalue">B</span> RPM</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: WOW! that did it! originally I has .specvalue and .row - it still didn't do anything.

rather than use .hide(), could I use .remove()?

reason being is, I'm coding the divs to appear in a striped pattern. by hiding the specs, I get inconsistencies.


EDIT: I just solved my own question! :D that indeed works!!

Answer (score 0):

All of your IDs are identical for each type of element - dont do that! Once you have fixed that, you will need to use the class as the selector, and then you could do something like this in jQuery:

```
if ($('.row').is(':empty')){
    $(this).parent()hide().
}
```

This then checks each element with the class row, and if it has no content, it gets that elements parent and hides it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in CSS, your problem is that you are using the same `id` attribute for each `span`. An `id` must be unique for the whole document ([see this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-id)). Use a `class` instead like this:

```
<span class="specvalue"><%=getAttribute('item','127559','custitem1','')%></span>
```

And the CSS:

```
.specvalue:empty {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So Like in your comment said already: ID's are Unique so use classes.

Here your solution: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joel_Jaun/ntxt39dr/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="itmSpecsTbl">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6" align="left">
    <b>Accuracy</b>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6" align="right">
    <span class="specvalue"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6" align="left">
    <b>Drive Type</b>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6" align="right">
    <span class="specvalue"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6" align="left">
    <b>Free Speed</b>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6" align="right">
    <span class="specvalue">RPM</span>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6" align="left">
    <b>Increments</b>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6" align="right">
    <span class="specvalue"></span>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Js:

```
var rows = $('#itmSpecsTbl .row');

$.each(rows, function(i, e){
    if($(e).find('.specvalue').text() === ''){
    $(e).hide();
  }
});
```